# How to compile scheme code to a bin file?

Tags: scheme, compilation, bin

I am using a software who has a built-in scheme interpreter. User could communicate and/or manipulate the software by typing command in the interpreter. The interpreter also could load scheme code file or bin file that contain scheme code. I wrote some scheme functions like this:

```
(define test (lambda(() (display "This is a test!")))
```

I will use the function "test" in the software interpreter later.
I don't want to anyone to change my code, so how can I compile this function into a bin file and load it to the interperter later?

Thanks a lot!!!

Joe

Comment: I think it may be difficult to answer this in the abstract. Can you tell us the software host and the specific Scheme system it is embedding?

Answer (score 0):

Interpreters don't run compiled code.

Comment: Bytecode interpreter run code compiled to bytecode. Emulators run machine code.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile all your scheme program with scheme compilers but not have an hybrid interpreted/compiled code

http://www.call-cc.org/

Yours